# Document DB with tableau

Tags: tableau-api, azure-cosmosdb

I installed cosmos DB drivers and connect to cosmos DB through tableau.
Whenever I connect to cosmos DB (Document DB) I am not getting data properly. some of the arrays(columns) are missing and some of the columns are not showing data properly. I installed CData ODBC Driver for Cosmos DB drivers and gave all the credentials. After that I tested it but I get the following error:

> system error: no such host is known.

How can I connect to cosmos DB through tableau?

Comment: The CData ODBC Driver for CosmosDB currently only supports the MongoDB API. If you haven't already, you can reach out to our [support team](https://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) to request that feature.

Answer (score 0):

> To obtain the connection string needed to connect to a Cosmos DB
>   account using the MongoDB API, log in to the Azure Portal, select
>   Azure Cosmos DB, and select your account. In the Settings section,
>   click Connection String.

Based on the [document](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cosmosdb-odbc-tableau.rst), only the `MongoDB API` is supported by ODBC Driver for CosmosDB. You could commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to ask your requirements about SQL API support.

Hope it helps you.